# Data disappears using MVVMLight EventToCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have successfully followed the dotnetcurry tutorial on mvvmlight here:  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1037.  This shows how to send data from one view to another, using MVVMLight's messaging via EventToCommand.  I've used the Northwind database to code my attempts, and can zip and send the solution if that helps.

I have a Window containing a number of views.  The left pane of the window displays a list of employees. Selecting an employee opens a) displays the employee detail in a middle pane and b) displays the list of orders processed by that employee in the right pane.  **What I'm trying to do** is make it so that clicking on one of the orders in the list shows order detail information (eg customer, order-line info) in the bottom pane.  **What happens** is clicking on the order makes the data in the order list and the employee detail view disappear.

[image: After clicking a row in the Employee Table]
The view after clicking a row in the Employee table (please excuse the UI, I know it ain't pretty).

[image: After clicking a row in the Order List]
The view after clicking one of the rows in the Order List on the right.  The whitespace below the view should now be filled with details about the selected order.

Some code:
EmployeeInfo.xaml  (Employee List)

```
<UserControl ...
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:mvvm="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
...
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" x:Name="dgEmployees" IsReadOnly="True" >
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SendEmployeeCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEmployees, Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

EmployeeOrderView.xaml  (List of Orders)

```
<Grid>
  <ListView Name="listOrders" ItemsSource="{Binding NewEmployee.Orders}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SendOrderCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listOrders, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView >
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderDate}" Header="Ordered" />
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Customer.CompanyName}" />
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ShippedDate}" Header="Shipped" />
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The Window (MainWindow.xaml) containing the views is just a grid comprised of the following:

```
<view:EmployeeInfo Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
<view:SaveEmployeeView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
<view:EmployeeOrderView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
<view:OrderCustomerView Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" />
```

MainViewModel:

```
[PreferredConstructor]
public MainViewModel(IDataAccessService proxy)
{
  serviceProxy = proxy;
  Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
  ReadAllCommand = new RelayCommand(GetEmployees);
  NewEmployee = new Employee();
  SaveCommand = new RelayCommand<Employee>(SaveEmployee);
  SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchEmployee);
  SendEmployeeCommand = new RelayCommand<Employee>(SendEmployee);
  ReceiveEmployee();
  SendOrderCommand = new RelayCommand<Order>(SendOrder);
  ReceiveOrderMessage();
}

public RelayCommand ReadAllCommand { get; set; }
public RelayCommand<Employee> SaveCommand { get; set; }
public RelayCommand SearchCommand { get; set; }
public RelayCommand<Employee> SendEmployeeCommand { get; set; }
public RelayCommand<Order> SendOrderCommand { get; set; }

// Properties (all properties in the same form as NewEmployee, but boilerplate code
// omitted for (some, at least) brevity)

public Employee NewEmployee
{
  get
  {
    return newEmployee;
  }
  set
  {
    if (newEmployee != value)
    {
      newEmployee = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("NewEmployee");
    }
  }
}
private Employee newEmployee;

public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees ...
private ObservableCollection<Employee> employees;

public string EmployeeName ...
private string employeeName;

public Order CurrentOrder...
private Order currentOrder;


void SendEmployee(Employee message)
{
  if (message != null)
  {
    Messenger.Default.Send<MessageCommunicator>(new MessageCommunicator()
    {
      EmployeeMessage = message
    });
  }
}

void ReceiveEmployee()
{
  if (NewEmployee != null)
  {
    Messenger.Default.Register<MessageCommunicator>(this, (emp) =>
      {
        this.NewEmployee = emp.EmployeeMessage;
      });
  }
}

void SendOrder(Order orderMessage)
{
  if (orderMessage != null)
  {
    Messenger.Default.Send<MessageCommunicator>(new MessageCommunicator()
      {
        OrderMessage = orderMessage
      });
  }
}

void ReceiveOrderMessage()
{
  if (CurrentOrder != null)
  {
    Messenger.Default.Register<MessageCommunicator>(this, (ord) =>
      {
        this.CurrentOrder = ord.OrderMessage;
      });
  }
}
```

I have debugged as far as showing that the Order Message is being sent correctly, but after that it jumps into assembly code and I'm a bit lost (I think it's looking for mvvmlight sources).

To me, it feels like a gui event is causing this to happen - I originally thought it was me not using mvvmlight's eventtocommand properly, but now I am not sure.  Can anyone explain why the data disappears or where it has gone?

Comment: EventToCommand has a host of problems including memory leaks. My best advice is to not use it.

Comment: @JonathanAllen so you think it *is* happening because of EventToCommand?  Can you suggest how I could confirm/deny this?

Comment: Doubtful. EventToCommand is a bad thing, but I can't think of how it would cause something like that.